# Why am I having ghosting and tearing with the i3 window manager paired with xcompgmr when tiling terminals vertically?

Tags: window-manager, window-title, i3

I'm using the [*i3*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I3_%28window_manager%29) tiling window manager. As it doesn't do compositing, I've enabled the `xcompmgr` compositor in my *~/.i3/config* file as well as `feh` to display a wallpaper:

```
exec --no-startup-id xcompmgr -c -C -t-5 -l-5 -r4.2 -o.55
exec feh --bg-scale ~/Downloads/Arch-Linux-Bluewave.jpg
```

Now `lxterminal` supports translucency etc. but when I arrange my terminals vertically, some **ghosting**, tearing and decoration artifacts from other workspaces appear to the top right - and disappear as soon as the window is tiled horizontally. Furthermore, when `transmission-gtk` "floats" a dialog box, moving that box around leaves ghosting in the form of tiny horizontal lines which remain until some refresh.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Not a solution, but something I've noticed in my configs: when I'm trying a bunch of configurations, this can happen a lot in some of my terminals. I'm running `compton` as my compositor. To get rid of it, I simply **shut-down and restart compton** and it goes away immediately. In my particular config (which came standard with Manjaro), this is done using `$mod+t` to shut down compton and `$mod+Ctrl+t` to start it up again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The symptoms arise from *two* distinct issues here:

1. The *compositor*: use something more recent like Compton in this case, with the following last options if supported by your hardware:

   ```
   exec --no-startup-id compton -cCGb --backend glx --vsync opengl
   ```
2. The fact that compositors are [*not officially supported*](http://bugs.i3wm.org/report/ticket/1254) by this window manager and [because](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/3279/do-i-need-a-composite-manager-compton/) of the way i3 renders window title bars. A well-known workaround is to disable such title bars by adding to `~/.i3/config`:

   ```
   new_window pixel
   ```

To move around a floating window with no titlebar, use `mod+drag` anywhere on it. Finally, some of this may change [over time](http://bugs.i3wm.org/report/ticket/661).

Comment: In looking at the documentation for Compton ( https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compton ), it looks like the -c argument enables shadows and the -CG part disables shadows.  It seems that the -c part wins in this case, and can cause the i3 title bar to produce a shadow over the associated window, giving a strange effect.  I've had better luck by omitting the -c portion.  Example:  compton -CGb --backend glx --vsync opengl